# Is there a reason not to declare all protobuf-net ProtoContract attribute classes with EnumPassthru=true

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

we currently have a client-server application which uses a number of protobuf-net serialized classes to conveniently communicate data objects.

In essence this application just proxies data from and to an underlying database to our clients also handling authentication and caching.

Our protobuf-net decorated classes are quite simple, but some also contain enum types.

Due to version updates which are not always completely rolled out to all clients we sometimes get the

> "No wire-value is mapped to the enum xxx"

error. This error has also occurred when having integers in a database which are casted to an enum type, which in pure c# is fine, but will cause the protobuf-net Exception.

In the cases where this occurred we have added the EnumPassthru option through `Protocontract(EnumPassthru = true)`.

Now I understand we could have designed the data objects to just be integers/longs in stead of the actual enum types if they are not actually used on the server side and cast them to the proper integer client side.

In order to make a better decision in what we should do I would like to know if there is any reason not to just declare all protobuf-serialized classes with the `EnumPassthru=true` option, which also better reflects C#'s default behavior.

Are there any caveats in doing a `"replace all [ProtoContract()] ==> [Protocontract(EnumPassthru = true)]"` ? I have tried this and have not discovered any issues in communicating with older versions which do not have this setting enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, none; I'd actually fully endorse doing this.

Basically, it comes down to google changing the spec. Originally, it was "correct" for unexpected enum values to cause the input to be rejected. However, since some point in "proto3" time (the last few years), they reversed their decision and decided that unexpected enum values should be *silently accepted* (at least when using "proto3").

So; recent protobuf-net versions (for about a year?) now use the "enum passthru" approach by default. Older protobuf-net versions: don't. If you have a mix of library versions for whatever reason, putting "enum passthru" everywhere is a very pragmatic and practical solution.

Note also that `[Flags]` enums have also always been treated as pass-thru.

There is also one scenario where new builds of protobuf-net *do not* use pass-thru by default; if you have something like:

```
public enum Foo {
    A,
    [ProtoEnum(Value=42)]
    B,
    C,
}
```

it can't use passs-thru here, as it needs to manually remap `B` (with value `1`) in your code to `42` on the wire